# executing a script from Python as root

Tags: python, unix, root

I'm writing a Python utility, which is part of an automation framework I'm writing for our software product. The goal of this utility is to install / uninstall the product at will ... so I have the following function:

```
def uninstall(self):
    # self.root is where the software is installed.
    if os.path.exists(self.root):
        if os.path.exists(self.uninstaller):
            os.chmod(self.uninstaller, 0777)
            # remove the product installation
            retval = subprocess.call(self.uninstaller, stdin=None,
                            stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
            if retval is not 0:
                "There was an error removing product"
                sys.exit(2)
        # remove the entire product directory
        shutil.rmtree(self.root)

    else:
        print "Product has already been removed"
        sys.exit(2)
```

the software product itself has a uninstaller (`self.uninstaller`), which needs to be executed as `root` in other to work. For my linux environment there isn't a password for the `root`, so

```
sudo ./Uninstall.sh
```

it's all what I need. However, in this case, I need to execute it from a python script ... What can I do to achieve that goal?

Comment: So you want to execute the python script as root, is that it? If thats the case then `sudo python uninstall.py`

Comment: @GamesBrainiac not necessarily ... the `Uninstall.sh` needs to be executed as root, but I have to do that from a python program ...

Comment: Try `os.system("sudo ./Uninstall.sh")`

Comment: Just execute your python script with `sudo` as @GamesBrainiac suggested